# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, caching

I use EF as ORM.

I dispose the `objectContext` on every request.

I save the entities in a cache layer, as my service gets lots of traffic.

I got sometimes get the error `objectContext already disposed` for some entities that I got from the cache.

I have added this code to elements that were retrived from the cache

```csharp
if (maMDBEntities.Entry(group).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
    maMDBEntities.Groups.Attach(group);
}
```

but now I sometimes get this error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Was using `Attach()` an incorrect solution from the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we told you in your other question ([will EF::attach(entity) will solve objectContext is already desposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724397/will-efattachentity-will-solve-objectcontext-is-already-desposed)), you have to detach the Entities before attaching it to another Context!

If `maMDBEntities` is a new Context (not the one, which loaded the data), the EntityState is not "attached" from this Contexts point-of-view. So your check is not sufficient.

This `maMDBEntities.Entry(group).State == EntityState.Detached` will **always** be true for an Context, which did not load the Entity.

Comment: why is my check not enough?

Comment: Because: `An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.` You are not doing clean work there. Detach it and you are fine.

Comment: so my check in meaningless. I see. So to sum up what I need to do: 1)EnableProxy = false 2)Force eager loading by using `Include()` fro every entity reference 3)Detach every entity reference ? Am i missing something or is any step redudant?

Comment: I think that's all. You could try using `AsNonTracked()` - this will load and detach entities.