# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am developing an application in MVC 5 and EF 6. I am using a generic method to update the entity and an extension method to detect the changed values and properties. When I try to insert updated record, I got the error,

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

My code for Update is:

```
public void Update(T data)
{
    var originalEntity = db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == data.Id);
    var modifiedValues = originalEntity.ModifiedValues<T>(data).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < modifiedValues.Count; i++)
    {
       string modifiedField = modifiedValues.ElementAt(i).Key;
       string modifiedValue = modifiedValues.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString();
       PropertyInfo prop = data.GetType().GetProperty(modifiedField, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
       string s = prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.Select(x => x.FullName).SingleOrDefault();
       switch (s)
       {
            case ("System.DateTime"):
            {
                DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(modifiedValue);
                prop.SetValue(data, d);
                break;
            }
            case ("System.String"):
            {
                prop.SetValue(data, modifiedValue);
                break;
            }
       }
   }
   Insert(data); // error occurred in this function
   Save();    
}
```

The code for Insert function is:

```
public void Insert(T data)
{ db.Set<T>().Add(data); }
```

at the statement **db.Set().Add(data);**, the error occurred.

I know this occurs when the entity is already attached to another Context. But in these functions I only use the context object *db* once but with **AsNoTracking()**, so this error shouldn't occur.

I looked to answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725831/an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetrac) and modify my Update function as:

```
db.Entry(data).State = EntityState.Detached;
Insert(data); // error again occurred in this function
Save();
```

But the error still occurs. What is the problem? How can I solve it?

I call the Update function from my COntroller:

```
private BaseRepository<ABC> g = new BaseRepository<ABC>();
ABC m = new ABC();
m = db.ABCs.Find(id);
m.S107 = "2";
m.D103 = DateTime.Now;
m.S36 = "awais";
g.Update(m);
```

Comment: How and where do you retrieve the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `m = db.ABCs.Find(id);`, which attaches the entity to the context.

Try exchanging it with `db.ABCs.AsNoTracking().Where(abc => abc.Id == id).First();`

From `DbSet.Find` documentation:

> ... request is made to the store for an entity with the given primary
>   key values and this entity, if found, **is attached to the context**
>   and returned. ...